# How can I use JavaScript Fetch to paginate through an API and return country names based on country code?

Tags: javascript, pagination, fetch

I'm totally clueless here

what i want my function to do is:-

- Match the country code and return counrty name
- if it does not find a match then increment the page number and make the fetch request again

App.js

```
// API endpoint: https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/countries?page=<PAGE_NUMBER>

async function getCountryName(code) {
    let pageNumber = 1
    const response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/countries?page=${pageNumber}`
    )
    const countries = await response.json()
    for (const x in countries.data) {
        if (countries.data[x].alpha2Code === code) {
            console.log(countries.data[x].name)
        }
    }
    // console.log(countries.total_pages)
    pageNumber++
    getCountryName()
}

getCountryName('AF')
```

i did try to put the fetch in a while loop but i cannot access the response outside the loop

Comment: You need to put the `fetch` in a while loop and keep going until the country is found or all pages are exhausted. Return the country name from the response inside of the `while` loop. If you're outside of the while loop, it means you didn't find the country, so return `null` or something.

Comment: tried it, but it did not work

Comment: When you call getCountryName the first thing it does is set pageNumber to 1.